# Default sorting on CrudRepository?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

Is it possible to add a default sorting to a `CrudRepository` method? Like:

```
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
   @SortDefault(sort = "lastname", direction = Sort.Direction.ASC) //this is invalid
   List<Person> findAllByAge(int age);
}

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id long id;
    String firstname, lastname;
    int age;
}
```

In contrast to `findAllByAge(int age, Sort sort);` the advantage would be not having to provide a `Sort` by each invoking class.

(sidenote: I know I could rename the class to `findAllByAgeSortLastnameAsc()`, but I'm explicit asking about @SortDefault annotation or similar).

Comment: Are you using  Spring data with Hibernate?

Comment: Yes I'm using the full stack provided by `spring-boot`, including hibernate mappings.

Comment: @membersound, `@SortDefault` isn't applied to methods, or did I miss something?

Comment: well, throwing this out there: you could always just implement that interface into having a custom implementation of that repository were you would just pass your Sort as desired, but calling it the method would be without the `sort` bit. I know, maybe not what is desired

Comment: @AndrewTobilko of course not, that's why I wrote "this is invalid" in the comment behind ;)

Comment: @sfat that's what I thought about as last resort.

Comment: @SortDefault must used with method param, in controller handler method. Just check documentation, there there are all what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following trick in your repo:

```
@Override
default Page<Person> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    return findAllBy(applyDefaultOrder(pageable));
}

Page<Person> findAllBy(Pageable pageable);

default Pageable applyDefaultOrder(Pageable pageable) {
    if (pageable.getSort().isUnsorted()) {
        Sort defaultSort = Sort.by("lastname").ascending();
        pageable = PageRequest.of(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), defaultSort);
    }
    return pageable;
}
```

This trick for example apply default ascending order by `lastname` field of the entity to the `findAll` metthed.

**UPDATED**

Another variant without `Pageable` as parameter:

```
@Override
default List<Person> findAll() {
    return findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "lastname"));
}
```

Or for an arbitrary method:

```
default List<Person> findAllByAge(int age) { 
    return findAllByAge(int age, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "lastname"));
} 

List<Person> findAllByAge(int age, Sort sort);
```

Comment: Is the same possible without `Pageable`, so that method invocations don't need to provide a parameter at all?

Comment: @membersound I updated the answer - may be this variant will be helpful...

Comment: Ok for the already existing `findAll()` interface this might work. But what about methods used in my initial question like `findAllByAge()`?

Comment: Is there a similar solution for spring 1.5.x? As `Sort.by()` is a spring 2.x method unfortunately..

Comment: @membersound [`new Sort(...)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.9.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html#Sort-org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Order...-)

Answer (score 0):

That would be a really cool feature tbh!

Depending on your DB the returned order may not be `what you expect`™. PostgreSQL for example seems to not order by asc/desc on PrimaryKey, but order by lastModified.

Right now there is no "indirect" solution of providing a Default-Sort-Order for surrogate / virtual (Repository-interface defined) methods (findByXYZ).

Your only option is to specify it explicitly by providing a Sort-Object

```
Sort.by("id"); //default is ASC
Sort.by(Sort.Order.desc("id"));
Sort sort = Sort.by("id").descending();
repo.findAll(sort);
```

or name the custom query method in your repository interface accordingly:

```
public interface YourEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<YourEntity, Long> {
        List<Entit> findAllByOrderById();
}
```

(note the neccessary extra 'By', even though no "where" clause is given)